# Meaning of fiddler's icon of blue < > angle brackets

Tags: fiddler

What is the meaning of this icon in Fiddler:

[image: Fiddler blue angle brackets]

It is not listed in the [help](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/UIGuide).

Comment: Can you add a snapshot of where you get this icon? For what resource type (flie type) are you having this icon? My guess is that it would be related to some code (html/script)

Comment: Sadly, the website help is outdated. You can see the current icons defined in the free sample of the FiddlerBook: http://www.fiddlerbook.com/book/DWF2-TOCAndSample.pdf

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This icon is used for responses with `Content-Type=Content-Type: text/html;`